# c++ how to access a pointer's struct variable

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to replicate a Binary Tree where the Nodes have a struct in its `Node` class. I can't seem to figure why it crashes when setting the `bookName` string. It keeps on crashing. Going to debug mode, it says it can't see the reference number or can't read the string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Book {
    string name;
};
struct TreeNode {
    float key;
    Book book;
    TreeNode* leftPtr;
    TreeNode* rightPtr;
};
class MyTree {
    TreeNode* rootPtr;
    // this function crashes!
    TreeNode* makeNode(float key,string bookName) {
        TreeNode* newNode = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            cout << "Error: No more space";
        }
        else {
            newNode->key = key;
            cout << newNode->book.name << endl;
            newNode->book.name = bookName;// CRASHES HERE
            cout << "Name: " << newNode->book.name;
            newNode->leftPtr = NULL;
            newNode->rightPtr = NULL;
        }
        return newNode;
    }
    TreeNode* insert(TreeNode* nodePtr, float key, string bookName) {
        if (nodePtr == NULL) {
            nodePtr = makeNode(key, bookName);
        }
        else if (key < nodePtr->key) {
            nodePtr->leftPtr = insert(nodePtr->leftPtr, key, bookName);
        }
        else if (key > nodePtr->key) {
            nodePtr->rightPtr = insert(nodePtr->rightPtr, key, bookName);
        }
        else { cout << "Error: Key already exist. Cannot add node."; }
        return nodePtr;
    }
public:
    MyTree() { rootPtr = NULL; }
    void addNode() {
        // ask for input
        float key = 0; string bookName = "default";
        cout << "Enter a value for the key: ";
        cin >> key;
        cout << "Enter the name for the book: ";
        cin >> bookName;

        // insert
        rootPtr = insert(rootPtr, key, bookName);
    }
};
int main() {
    MyTree a;
    a.addNode();
}
```

The debug error message is this:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0121DA2E in Assessment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

Please help

---

Edit 1:
Replaced the malloc as suggested but it crashes when setting the `key` variable.

```cpp
TreeNode* makeNode(float key,string bookName) {
        cout << "Here";
        TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode;// CRASHES HERE
        cout << "Here";
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            cout << "Error: No more space";
        }
        else {
            newNode->key = key;
            newNode->book.name = bookName;
            cout << "Name: " << newNode->book.name;
            newNode->leftPtr = NULL;
            newNode->rightPtr = NULL;
        }
        return newNode;
    }
```

Comment: The exception means that you read through an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `new` does not return a null pointer, so no need to check. (And it's spelled `nullptr` for quite some time now).

Comment: Remember that output to `std::cout` is *buffered*, so unless you flush the output (with e.g. `std::endl`) you can't reliably use it for locating crashes. Use an actual debugger to run the program and catch the crash "in action".

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the crash](https://ideone.com/TafL8T). Please make sure you are running the program you think you are running. Also, when you post code, post all of it, do not omit `#include` directives and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TreeNode* newNode = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
```

Don't do this. Your `TreeNode` contains an `std::string`, which needs to be properly initialized. With `malloc` you don't initialize anything, you just allocate memory. So when you try to use the string, it's most likely in some invalid state and will cause nothing but trouble. There aren't many reasons to use `malloc` in C++, better just do this instead:

```
TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode;
```

And when it's not needed anymore, do `delete newNode;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing `malloc` with the `new TreeNode` made it crash as soon as the code attempted to set the `key` variable

Comment: That change made it work for me. What input are you testing it with?

Comment: the number `1` and `a`

Comment: Whoops. I checked again. Apparently, it crashes on the new TreeNode line.

Comment: That's unusual. What reason does the debugger give for the crash?

Comment: It says `Exception thrown at 0x00E80560 in Assessment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

Comment: nvm. I was able to solve it. apparently, I forgot to remove the `=NULL` from the Book's `name` variable in the struct.

Comment: @CraftedGaming One of the lessons here: Always include a [mcve] that **replicates** the problem you have. Also, this second crash should have been asked about as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

If you search a little for the pattern `0xCDCDCDCD` you will quickly find out that it's what the debug-build of `malloc` uses to fill the memory it allocates. That in turn means you use uninitialized memory in your program. You allocate memory with `malloc` but you don't initialize the memory.

And that allocation with `malloc` is the root cause of your problem. The `malloc` function allocates memory, but it doesn't call object constructors. That in turn means that the `std::string` object of the `Book` structure is not constructed, and using it in any way leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution, beyond [reading good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn C++ properly, is to use the `new` operator to allocate your object:

```
TreeNode* newNode = new TreeNode;
```